# As long as features are same does MCU Case Style make a difference?

Tags: microcontroller

I recently got into the field of Microcontrollers and it is my first time buying a custom one (other than arduinos and rasp pis) and I noticed these 2 on the shopping pages…
[image]
My question is that since both of these have only MCU Case Style difference feature-wise, is there any difference in the actual thing other than the case style, (life, interoperability, tips etc.). Also is a difference in the case style gonna make it hard for me to use it on an average breadboard? Do you have any tips for which one should be preferred and if not any major difference should I just go for the cheaper one since there isn’t much difference anyways??

https://in.element14.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/microcontrollers-mcu/16-32-bit-microcontrollers-mcu-avr/prl/results?ost=microcontroller&sort=P_PRICE

Comment: It would be a lot better if you had given the URL to the supplier page you were viewing.  In general, most of the time if the pin count is the same the processor works the same.  But in some cases, when the pin count is different, the processor works differently. DIP packages are easiest for hobbyists to work w/. But are seldom made these days.  I think the hardest are the QFN packages.  These look like "flat packs" which have fine pitch (you will need an adapter to use on a bread board) but are no where near as difficult as lead-less QFN packages.

Comment: https://in.element14.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/microcontrollers-mcu/16-32-bit-microcontrollers-mcu-avr/prl/results?ost=microcontroller&sort=P_PRICE

Comment: please remove the quotation marks around the URL ... the link will become clickable

Answer (score 1):

Notice the [Microchip](https://www.microchip.com/) [specifications](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3165060.pdf) for either of the pictured processors is the same document on the vendors web page.  On the second page there is a breakdown on the processor numbering scheme:

[image]

... the only difference between the two selected processors are the last to characters.  SS and SO.  From the above image we see this is used to specify either SSOP or SOIC packaging.  Neither will plug in to most 1/10 inch spaced breadboards with out an adapter.

Here is an image of a TSSOP to 1/10 inch bread board adapter:

[image]

... likely you can use such a PCB to convert the processor ending in SO so that it can be used on a 1/10 inch bread board.